# How to veriy/by pass OTP received on mobile using cypress?

Tags: authentication, cypress, one-time-password

I am automating an application in which user need to enter username/email and then he needs to enter Password as well as Verification  Code received on SMS. The Verification Code entered is valid for 24 hours and user will not be prompted to enter verification code again till next 24 hours.
I saw a way by passing session tokens but they are valid only after user clicks on login button I guess.

I am using Cypress to automate this application. Any idea how can I overcome this . It would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: You may want to check with your team for any codes that can bypass the verification

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-otp ?